# Constant GitHub Pushes and contributions

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have recently learnt about git and concepts of code repositories like GitHub. According to my readings so far, most people who use GitHub , use it to showcase their project, build their reputation as an open source contributor (apart from other uses like collaboration, version management,etc).

Now, the first thing that would catch most people's eye whenever we visit anyone's profile is their contribution graph. I have noticed that any minor pushes to our repositories are considered as contribution. **I wonder why anyone wouldn't just keep pushing  minor changes in their existing codebases** just to increase their count of number of contribution on profile and make it look like they are actively working on their projects and making many contributions.

Is there any restriction on **number of GitHub push** I can perform and what if there's any, are the disadvantages of committing so many pushes?

Comment: The behavior you're describing is utterly and personally dishonest, and it's out there where anyone who doesn't actually believe counting things is a good metric for contribution in engineering and design work can see it. Anyone trying to fool the people who *do* believe that, well, I'd say they deserve each other, and if github wants to promote a mutual admiration society for that crowd, it's probably a public service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see *github* or other services for versioning management with git (gitlab, bitbucket ...) rather as *source code management* as a *presentation* of *how many commits* have been made per repository... As far as I know there is no restriction on commits per day, but I have never heard of anyone tracking the number of commits/contributions on the *github* account.

I find fewer contributions on a git repository more **clearly** and more **professional** anyway than as many as possible...

And when a job hunter looks at your git repository, he will see if it has unnecessary posts and can also see the differences between the different posts if the project is public.

So I would prefer to make *few* contributions/commits, but *meaningful* according to the principle **"less is more"**.

Comment: I though there must probably have been some limit on number of push per day or minimum changes required before another push can be made. Well, thanks for the answer anyways.

Comment: No, I don't know anything about that and have never received a message that I have to wait until I can make another contribution. Good succeed

Answer (score 2):

> According to my readings so far, most people who use GitHub , use it to showcase their project, build their reputation as an open source contributor (apart from other uses like collaboration, version management,etc).

I claim that this is false. In fact, I claim that most people who use GitHub use it to create and improve open source software, with reputation only a secondary concern. Of course it's possible to boost your metrics, whenever there are any metrics to boost, but your commit history on GitHub is public; if anyone wants to see what you *actually did*, what contributions you *actually made*, they can find out.

I believe you see GitHub primarily as a social network, whereas I see it primarily as a code repository.

---

Note that if you're pushing to repositories that you don't maintain yourself, then your pull requests are likely to require review by a maintainer before they end up in master. Frivolous pull requests in that setting are likely to get you completely ignored for the future.

Comment: Ofcourse,one of main usage of GitHub is the collaboration and contributions to the open-source(as I did mention in my question). But many time, it also stands as a metric to judge how well a developer you are. Even some companies use it as hiring criteria to some extent. A profile with say 1000 contribution will probably look better than someone's profile with say 500 contributions but both did a project of about same level. And my main question was, is there anything that stops people from constant pushes to GitHub?

Comment: Well, if you declare that you have a thousand contributions, and then your prospective employer looks at your commit history and finds that your commits are all frivolous, then you've got your punishment.

Comment: ofcourse that's easy if my repository is fairly small. But after a point, nobody's gonna scavenge throughout our repo to find if every push was legit, isn't it?

Comment: But the prospective employer can see that you're committing only to a couple of repos which you own. They'll be much more impressed if you're committing to other repos (which, remember, have maintainers who are gate-keeping commits), or if you're a maintainer on a repo that's busy with committers who are not you.